# My iPhone 5s is not working with horizontal rotation using Titanium Alloy

Tags: javascript, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium

My application is working with all rotations in Android and iPad devices, but my new iPhone 5s is not working with horizontal rotation. It remains vertical when the iPhone is rotated horizontally. For that I already added below code in my Tiapp.xml file :

```
<orientations device="iphone">
            <orientation>Ti.UI.PORTRAIT</orientation>
            <orientation>Ti.UI.UPSIDE_PORTRAIT</orientation>
            <orientation>Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT</orientation>
            <orientation>Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_RIGHT</orientation>
</orientations>
```

Also, I followed as per described in this https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204547 link, but it did not work for me in my new iPhone

Answer (score 1):

You are using a configuration method which has been deprecated and possibly removed for a long time already. You can find the current way to limit the orientation modes in the following guide:

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Orientation-section-29004932_Orientation-LimitingorientationmodesoniOS

Comment: I have tried to make it according to above link but its still not working.

Comment: Could you share the `<ios>` section of your `tiapp.xml` and perhaps create and upload/link a small project demonstrating the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is my code which i have place in Tiapp.xml File inside `<ios>`..`</IOS>` SECTION

```
<ios>
        <plist>
            <dict>
                <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~iphone</key>
                <array>
                    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
                </array>
                <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
                <array>
                    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
                    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
                    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
                    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </plist>
    </ios>
```

Is this proper?
After placing this in Tiapp.xml, still My iphone 5-s is NOT Working with horizontal rotation. It stays as vertical still it's in horizontal mode.

Comment: This code indeed forces it to portrait only for iPhone. @prashant's code shows how to support all orientations. Be aware that it is advised to not use `UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown` to not confuse users when call comes in.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ios>
        <plist>
            <dict>
                <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~iphone</key>
                <array>
                    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
                  <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
                    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
                    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
                </array>
                <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
                <array>
                    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
                  <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
                    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
                    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </plist>
    </ios>
```

Use the above code & make sure to turn on the rotation in your iPhone.